# how to use laravel resources for relationship both side

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have a "many to many" relationship

`category belongstomany jobs` 
and 
`job belongstomany categories`

I have two resources: `CategoryResources` and `JobResources`

They are like this:

CategoryResources

```
'name' => $this->name,
'slug' => $this->slug,
'icon' => $this->icon,
'created_at' => $this->created_at->diffForHumans(),
'jobs' => JobResources::collection($this->jobs)
```

JobResources

```
'id' => $this->id,
'title' => $this->title,
'slug' => $this->slug,
'description' => $this->description,
'type' => new TypeResources($this->type),
'categories' => CategoryResources::collection($this->categories)
'created_at' => $this->created_at->diffForHumans()
```

The problem is that it's taking infinite time to fetch the data. How could I prevent this?

As an alternative I made different resources like `JobReverseResource`, but its wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You've got a circular reference. Jobs fetch categories, which fetch jobs, which fetch categories, forever and ever.

Answer (score 2):

The reason could be they are calling each other continuously, as a result, it's getting infinite to get data. Or another reason could be you are trying to fetch data before they are ready for you. You can give a try to following code:

```
// eager loading categories
'categories' => CategoryResources::collection(Category::with('jobs')->get())

// or in case you want them after fetching all data
$category->load('jobs');

// eager loading jobs
'jobs' => JobResources::collection(Job::with('categories')->get())
// or in case you want them after fetching all data
$jobs->load('categories');
```